# define request body in spring colud contract

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract

I want to write a contract using spring cloud contract in producer API.

Here is my API:

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/person",
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<PersonInfo> test(@RequestBody PersonRequest request){
    PersonInfo personInfo = bankService.getPersonInfo(request);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(personInfo, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

My DSL in groovy :

```
  Contract.make {
   description("spring cloud contract")
   request {
   method 'POST'
   url '/person'
   headers {
    contentType(applicationJson())
  }
   body("""
 {
   "nationalId": "2548745"
 }
    """)

 }
  response {
 status 200
 body("""
 {
   "name": "Marc",
   "family": "Brown",
   "gender": "M"
}
""")
  headers {
     contentType(applicationJson())
   }
  }
}
```

PersonRequest :

```
public class PersonRequest {
private String nationalId;


public String getNationalId() {
    return nationalId;
}

public void setNationalId(String nationalId) {
    this.nationalId = nationalId;
}
```

}

Now when I clean and install the project I get this error :

Expecting:
<415>
to be equal to:
<200>
but was not.

If I change `@RequestBody PersonRequest request` to `@RequestBody String request` everything works fine.

I am using spring boot 2.3.1.RELEASE and spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier 2.2.3.RELEASE and junit5

I test this case with junit4 and it is ok. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is it related to this issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/1428

Comment: I see this issue but unfortunately I can not recognize how to change my DSL to fix this problem. @MarcinGrzejszczak

Comment: Don't change the dsl, change the base class RestAssuredMockMvc.config = new RestAssuredMockMvcConfig() .encoderConfig(new EncoderConfig(UTF_8.name(), UTF_8.name())); or opt-out appending of default content charset: EncoderConfig encoderConfig = new EncoderConfig() .appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false); RestAssuredMockMvcConfig restAssuredConf = new RestAssuredMockMvcConfig() .encoderConfig(encoderConfig); RestAssuredMockMvc.config = restAssuredConf;

Comment: Really appreciate.Now it works fine. @MarcinGrzejszczak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change the dsl, change the base class

```
RestAssuredMockMvc.config = new RestAssuredMockMvcConfig() .encoderConfig(new EncoderConfig(UTF_8.name(), UTF_8.name()));
```

or opt-out appending of default content charset:

```
EncoderConfig encoderConfig = new EncoderConfig() .appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false); RestAssuredMockMvcConfig restAssuredConf = new RestAssuredMockMvcConfig() .encoderConfig(encoderConfig); RestAssuredMockMvc.config = restAssuredConf;
```